# How do i make python find differing elements in a list and their number of occurrences within it

Tags: python, list

Say i have a list x and :
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a']

if a user, or another programmer, does not know the elements in a list, how do I tell python to find the unique elements So if they ask (what is in this list?) python would output:
in this list there are **3** different elements : **a, b** and **c**

and if the user asks (how many of each) python should output:
ie - (in this list, there are **4** instances of **c**, **2** instances of **a** and **1** instance of **b**)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

Look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a']
counter = collections.Counter(x)
print(len(counter))  # 3
print(counter)  # Counter({'c': 4, 'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```
ItemList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'A']
NewDict = {}

for Item in ItemList:
  if Item not in NewDict:
    NewDict[Item] = 0
  NewDict[Item] += 1

print(NewDict)
```

And if you don't want respect the case:

```
ItemList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'A']
NewDict = {}

for Item in ItemList:
  if Item.lower() not in NewDict:
    NewDict[Item.lower()] = 0
  NewDict[Item.lower()] += 1

print(NewDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution without `collections.Counter`:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a']
print(len(set(x)))
print([f"{i} - {x.count(i)}" for i in set(x)])
```